# Insert into table SQlite 2 variables Lua

Tags: sqlite, lua

I have two Lua string variables, need to put these two strings into a table in SQlite.

Two variables like this:

```
s = "Jack"
b = "designer"
```

I think it's something like this, but it's wrong:

```
"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" .. s .. "," .. b .. ")"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using any particular library, module, or binding to access SQLite from Lua?

Comment: And what is wrong about that? Do you get an error?

Comment: Probably, you need to enclose values in apostrophes `"... VALUES('" .. s .. "','" .. b .. "')"`. But you'd better user parameters binding from your SQLite framework/library.

Comment: Yes, i have error with that, I am not using any library, is SQlite, into Lua, I have error, because, i think that SQLite, can't know what are these variables.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Only the code isn't function, when i print the values of the table, i don't see anything

Answer (score -1):

> INSERT INTO table_name
>   VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

make sure the values are in the same order as the attributes in the table.

Comment: And how is this different from the SQL in the question?

Comment: I was pointing out that "values" (value1, value2, value3) should be in the correct order.

Comment: The code need to be SQLite vor introduce the variables i believe.